# replace particular line with user provided variable with sed

Tags: sed

My code is like below; and it is not working.

```sh
line_number=$1;
variable1=$2;

sed '\$line_number c\
\$variable1' file > tmp.out
```

If I write like below then its working. Can you please suggest how can I make above code running?

```sh
sed '1 c\
<replace>abc</replace>' file > tmp.out
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the variables out of single quotes, and you don't need any backslash before the variables:

```sh
sed "$line_number"' c\ 
'"$variable1" file > tmp.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```sh
#!/bin/bash

line_number=$1;
variable1=$2;

sed "$line_number c\
$variable1" file > tmp.out
```

If you want to use your variables values inside sed, then you have use `"` (double quotes).
Then, It will be interpreted by shell.